# Android SDK Manager: Bug when connecting to a proxy (empty username), can you confirm that?

Tags: android, proxy, android-studio, http-proxy, android-sdk-manager

I am using Android Studio, and Android SDK Manager 24.0.2 to keep my packages up to date. Unfortunately, I am working in a company that requires a HTTP Proxy for connections to the web, so every app that does not use the default settings of my Windows operating system needs proxy configuration data, and it also works in alsmost every application, except Android SDK manager.

Precisely, I start SDK Manager, go to Tools -> Options, configure proxy and port.
Since our proxy requires login information, I provide Username and Password, but that doesn't work. So I looked at our proxy's logfiles, and noticed that every information I entered goes to the proxy, except for the username!

So my impression is that there is a bug in the proxy dialog in SDK Manager that causes the contents of the editline where I enter the **username** not to actually be transferred to the proxy, the other three editlines (Password, Workstation and Domain) are transferred however.

Can anybody familiar with SDK Manager please have a look at this and confirm that? Or give me any other hint what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: SInce nobody seems to know an answer, where is the best place to ask this question? I alread tried the following:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/android-developers This forum is moderated, and I tried to ask this question there twice in the last few days, but it never gets published, but I do not get a notification what was wrong with that question

- https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list - tried to report the bug on the bugtracker, but this seems to be only a place for spammers, and Google doesn't seem to care.

So how can one get in touch with the SDK Manager developers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official way for reporting bugs is described here:
https://source.android.com/source/report-bugs.html

But like you said, it´s only a place for spammers and Google dosen´t care.